# Access to the boxes of a Matrix

Tags: java

I'd like to create a matrix like this one:

[image: matrix]

It's the transform of a graph in a matrix where `a`, `b`, `c` and so on are the vertices and the values represent `0` if the vertices are disconnected and `1` if they're connected.

I take two vertices randomply (i.e. `c` and `d`) and I'd like to access the value of those vertices in the matrix as M[c][d] and, also, M[d][c].

How can I do this?

Comment: i transform a graphe in a matrix, a,b,c...are the vertices , o if independents and 1 if vertices dependents. then i take two vertices randomly (exp: c and d) and i'd like to acced to the value M[c][d] and also M[d][c]

Comment: yes, but in terms of code - what have you tried?
what is your array made of? characters, Strings, integers?
How do you try to access the desired cell? etc. etc.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trylly want to use letters (`chars`) as indexes then you'll have to take an alternative approach. You can create your own structure that takes `char` as an index. Since a two dimensional array can be seen as an array of arrays, you can use a `Map` or `Map` objects.

You won't be able to access the objects the way you expect with this, instead you'll have to invoke `map.get('c').get('d')`.

Another approach is to create a sort of "rosetta stone" that translates your `char` into the corresponding index. This is particulary useful for small graphs, since big ones generate inmense matrices and getting the index there depends on how will you address them. For example:

```
public class IndexInterpreter {

    //Using a switch here to illustrate, you can make your own mapping logic.
    public static int getIndex(char letter) {
        switch(letter) {
            case 'a':
                return 0;
            case 'b':
                return 1;
            //the swtich goes on and on...         
        }
    }
}
```

and then, while calling the matrix you just translate the letters into their corresponding indexes:

```
int i1 = IndexInterpreter.getIndex('c');
int i2 = IndexInterpreter.getIndex('d');  
m[i1][i2]
```

or, if you like

```
m[IndexInterpreter.getIndex('c')][IndexInterpreter.getIndex('d')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will use integer indexes instead of letters you will be able to say `m[2][3]`, if the matrix is defined as: `int[][] m`;

If you need to access the values using string coordinates, probably you should take a look at the Table class from Guava, see: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html. 
This way, you will be able to declare your matrix like: `Table<String,String,String>` and insert values using: `put(String rowKey, String columnKey, String value)` method and access them using `get(String rowKey, String columnKey)`

Comment: Thank you @MyNameIsTooCommon and user1543915 for changing the negative down vote :).

Answer (score 0):

matrix would be a 2D array

```
String[][] matrix = new String[6][7]
```

you could then populate it using

```
matrix[1][1] = "1";
```

To get the cell you want you wuld do

```
String val = mattix[3][5];
```

This [link](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html) may help